# Margin messing with the position property

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    li {
        float: left;
    }
    li a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #111;
    }
    .active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>

<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:30px;background-color:#1abc9c;height:1500px;">
    <h1>Fixed Top Navigation Bar</h1>
    <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
    <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my code I am trying to have a fixed navigation bar.
The "ul" tag is first thing in my body so when I set "position: fixed" it should  be on top but it isn't. I had to specify "top: 0" for that. I found that the styles associated with my div are causing this problem. I don't understand why the div is behaving in such a way.

If you do not understand what I am saying remove the "top: 0" from the styles associated with "ul" you'll see a white strip at the top. That white strip is because of the margin specified for the div.
I just want to know, why the white strip is there? Also because if I do not specify "top: 0" my navigatin bar comes below that margin.

Also,
when I say "position: fixed" I also had to specify the as "width: 100%". But without the position property the width of the "ul" is by default "100%"

Comment: The white strip does not depend on whether you set top:0 or not, it is _always_ there - if you don't believe it, remove the background colors from your navigation, then you'll see it. The reason why is called collapsing margins/adjoining margins, go read up on it. And the width of an absolute or fixed positioned element is calculated by a method called shrink-to-fit - it is _specified_ this way.

Comment: First, you haven't removed padding from body, only margin. It's usually wise to use some sort of reset.css in the beginning to get an even playing field. That probably has something to do with it. To avoid the issue with width playing in, you can do `position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;` which will stretch it from left to right.